# dplyr returns global mean for each group, instead of each groups mean

Tags: r, dplyr

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here:

```
library(dplyr)
temp<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),b=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3))
temp%>%group_by(temp[,1])%>%summarise(n=n(),mean=mean(temp[,2],na.rm=T))

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  `temp[, 1]`     n  mean
        <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1           1     3     2
2           2     3     2
3           3     3     2
```

I expected the means to be:

```
1  1
2  2
3  3
```

instead the mean seems to be the global mean (all values in col 2 divided by the number of instances) = 18/9=2

How do I get the mean to be what I expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calculating the mean of `temp[,2]`instead of the column in the group (`mean(temp[,2],na.rm=T)` does not depend on the context at all). You need to do the following:

```
> temp %>% group_by(temp[,1]) %>% summarise(n=n(), mean=mean(b, na.rm=T))
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  `temp[, 1]`     n  mean
        <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1           1     3     1
2           2     3     2
3           3     3     3
```

Furthermore it is more common to use the column name in the `group_by` as well:

```
> temp %>% group_by(b) %>% summarise(n=n(), mean=mean(b, na.rm=T))
# A tibble: 3 × 3
      b     n  mean
  <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1     1     3     1
2     2     3     2
3     3     3     3
```

Comment: I'd probably avoid the use of indices in the `group_by` as well.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(temp)[, .(n = .N, mean = mean(b)), by = a]
#   a n mean
#1: 1 3    1
#2: 2 3    2
#3: 3 3    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Always remember to use column names in `dplyr`. you will run into problems like these when you try to reference column by their index rather than name. so instead of the code you used

```
temp%>%group_by(temp[,1])%>%summarise(n=n(),mean=mean(temp[,2],na.rm=T))
```

Try the below this. gives the expected result

```
 temp%>%group_by(b)%>%summarise(n=n(),mean=mean(b))
```